# Does the absorption intensity for vibrational transition depends on the angle between the electric field vector and the transition moment vector?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Is the transition possible even if there is a certain angle between the electric field vector and the transition moment, given that the photon and molecule are in resonance. My notion is that the transition is not possible since the energy is purely due to the varying electric field and the force on the molecule depends on the angle between the force vector and the transition moment vector, so even a small angle reduces the amount of force experienced by the molecule and therefore the energy transferred will be less than the required energy for the transition. What are your opinions? Thank you.